# Deleting a very large number of files - will multiple processes make this faster?

Tags: windows, dma

I have a very large number of files to delete.

If I do this in a batch script, I can do `del /S *` and then spawn multiple shells to do the same.

Will calling the delete function multiple times through multiple processes speed up my deletion of files?

Because the DMA cycles every second are fixed, any removal of files will involve removal of its entry from Master file table and will consist of removing those entries using the DMA cycles. Would this mean multiple delete processes could therefore remove files more quickly?

Or, will this slow me down because now several processes will need a lock on the File Table?

Comment: It will most likely be somewhat slower, since you're limited by shared I/O. Why don't you simply test and measure?

Comment: I vote for slower using multiple shells - your multiple shells will have to fight for the same resource anyway.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I had a very large folder, a result of my automation creating temp files and not removing them. Now, I deleted them and I don't have the system anymore. I will take me some time to set up the whole thing to accurately measure this.

Comment: They normally make it significantly slower.  Forcing the disk drive to seek back-and-forth to keep them all happy.  Seeking is the single most expensive thing you can do with a drive.  More processes doesn't buy you more disks.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the underlying file system and how well it deals with concurrency. Trying to do this on FAT vs NTFS (since you seem to be using Windows) will probably show significantly different results. And in the Linux world, you would also get different results for EXT2/3/4, XFS, JFS, ReiserFS, BtrFS, .... Journalling file systems will typically be somewhat better at things like this, but there will be quite a bit of variance even then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately depends on the file system type, hard disk type, hard disk seek time, whether the data lives on a SAN, IOPS, RAID levels, etc. You may get slight improvement by running two delete commands at once; however, there are so many variables that the best method to determine the answer would be to do a test.

Comment: How does that matter? I thought delete just means the removal of some entry in the file table, not actual scrubbing of the file. Could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Right, I removed the comment about files sequential on the disk; however, If the entries of files to be deleted in the MFT were sequential there may be a performance improvement running simultaneous delete commands because the drive would be doing sequential writes to the MFT.
If a file is very small, just a few bytes, e.g a cookie, there is no need for the the MFT entry to have a index directing the computer to the location of the cookie (as the directions could be longer than the file), instead it can fit the small file in the MFT entry – where the index or directions would normally be.

Comment: But, aren't the DMA cycles constant? won't multiple processes writing and a single process writing be the same? I mean, the bottleneck is the IO operation through the DMA where the Table is being written.

Comment: DMA is used to transfer data to and from memory on the host in a way that doesn't interrupt the CPU. I'm not certain, but I wouldn't think DMA is relevant to multiple delete operations since there shouldn't be anything referencing host memory except the process performing the delete. I think the write IOPS of the disk subsystem will be the biggest bottleneck.